# Django routing - The empty path did not match any of these

Tags: python, django

Using the `URLconf` defined in `pccb_model.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
predictive/
admin/
```

The empty path didn't match any of these.

[image: img]

Comment: Please post your error message including the full error traceback and the related code as text, no screenshots of textual information. Also make it a proper question don't just dump the error message here!

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, you need to define a view for a default path in your *pccb_model.urls* module. Make sure you have a corresponding method in the *views.py*. For example:

urls.py

```
path('', views.index)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('test', status=200)
```